Jitsi Meet Static Files Not Loading Correctly in Server
I am working on running jisti web on my server i was able to work it correctly in my local at http://0.0.0.0:8085/
this is my docker compose file
services:

  project_one_frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3005:3000"
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
      - project_one_backend
    env_file:
      - .docker_env_demo
    restart: always

  project_one_jitsi_web:
    image: jitsi/web:stable
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8444:8443"     # For HTTPS access (if SSL is set up)
      - "8085:80"        # Change to an available port on the host
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
        - project_one_jitsi_jvb

  project_one_jitsi_prosody:
    image: jitsi/prosody:stable
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network

  project_one_jitsi_jicofo:
    image: jitsi/jicofo:stable
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
        - project_one_jitsi_prosody

  project_one_jitsi_jvb:
    image: jitsi/jvb:stable
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "10000:10000/udp"
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
        - project_one_jitsi_prosody

networks:
  backend_network:

but when i put in my server it should run correctly at https://project-one.org/v_call_ser/
but i only get the page not the static files like css, js etc, this is my nginx.conf file
server {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    server_name project-one.org;

    # Set timeouts
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    # Frontend location
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3005;  # Direct to the frontend service
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Jitsi Video Call Server
    location /v_call_ser/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 
        # Rewrite paths for static files
        sub_filter '/libs/' '/v_call_ser/libs/';
        sub_filter '/css/' '/v_call_ser/css/';
        sub_filter '/js/' '/v_call_ser/js/';
        sub_filter_once off;

        # Disable compression to allow sub_filter
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    }


    # Handle 502 Bad Gateway
    error_page 502 /project_one/index.html;  # Custom error page for 502

    # SSL and Certbot configurations
    listen 443 ssl;  # Managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/project-one.org-0001/fullchain.pem;  # Managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/project-one.org-0001/privkey.pem;  # Managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;  # Managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;  # Managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = project-one.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    server_name project-one.org;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


and this is the .jitsi_env_demo env file
CONFIG=~/.jitsi-meet-cfg
HTTP_PORT=8000
HTTPS_PORT=8443
TZ=UTC
BASE_URL=https://project-one.org/v_call_ser
XMPP_DOMAIN=meet.jitsi
XMPP_SERVER=xmpp.meet.jitsi
PUBLIC_URL=https://project-one.org/v_call_ser
JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIGASI_XMPP_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIGASI_TRANSCRIBER_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIBRI_RECORDER_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIBRI_XMPP_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
RESTART_POLICY=unless-stopped
JITSI_IMAGE_VERSION=stable

when i check the network tab in server I see the static files are not loaded correctly
they are loading like this
https://project-one.org/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js?v=8242
with 404 error
but when i check update the url and check like this
https://project-one.org/v_call_ser/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js?v=8242
I get the correct page, so what I need to fix this ?

Where did you get the nginx configuration you’ve shared? Did you write it yourself or use some reference? I couldn’t find a description of the Jitsi env file parameters (if you have one, please share the link), but judging by the BASE_URL/PUBLIC_URL values, it’s highly likely that the Jitsi web server is capable of generating correct asset links prefixed with /v_call_serv on its own. If that’s the case, the sub_filter configuration part in your nginx setup is likely disrupting them.

I got the configuration from chatgpt. I got the env variable to add to jitsi from this repo https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet. I tried without the sub_filter block also same issue.

I couldn’t find any mention of the BASE_URL parameter in the env_example or docker_compose.yml files from the GitHub repository, nor in the "Self-Hosting Guide - Docker" documentation page. The description of the PUBLIC_URL parameter seems somewhat unclear. The first thing you should try is removing everything from # Rewrite paths for static files to proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; in your nginx configuration (and don’t forget to reload nginx afterward). Please share the results you achieve.

I tried to set up a deployment similar to yours. Upon inspecting the HTML generated by the Jitsi Meet engine, it turns out that the responses already include relative links for assets, such as:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css?v=...">

However, Jitsi Meet utilizes the nginx SSI (Server Side Includes) feature to include several pre-built HTML files in its responses. One of these files, /usr/share/jitsi-meet/base.html, is responsible for generating the final asset links that the user's browser will request. By default, its content is as follows:
<base href="/" />

To ensure that assets are requested using your custom URI prefix, you need to modify this file as follows:
<base href="/v_call_ser/" />

The default NGINX configuration template already attempts to accommodate a custom URI prefix. Relevant parts of the /defaults/meet.conf template include:
    # BOSH for subdomains
    location ~ ^/([^/?&:'"]+)/http-bind {
        set $subdomain "$1.";
        set $subdir "$1/";
        set $prefix "$1";

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /http-bind;
    }

    {{ if $ENABLE_XMPP_WEBSOCKET }}
    # websockets for subdomains
    location ~ ^/([^/?&:'"]+)/xmpp-websocket {
        set $subdomain "$1.";
        set $subdir "$1/";
        set $prefix "$1";

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /xmpp-websocket;
    }
    {{ end }}

and
# BOSH
location = /http-bind {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host {{ $XMPP_DOMAIN }};

    proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }}/http-bind?prefix=$prefix&$args;
}

{{ if $ENABLE_XMPP_WEBSOCKET }}
# xmpp websockets
location = /xmpp-websocket {
    tcp_nodelay on;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host {{ $XMPP_DOMAIN }};
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }}/xmpp-websocket?prefix=$prefix&$args;
}
{{ end }}

However, this line:
set $prefix "";

causes the prefix query argument passed to the jitsi/prosody backend to always be empty. I modified the default meet.conf template to fix this issue and added some optimizations that should not alter nginx behavior. Below is the meet.conf.patch file containing these modifications:
42c42
<     alias /config/config.js;
---
>     root /config;
46c46
<     alias /config/interface_config.js;
---
>     root /config;
50c50
<     alias /usr/share/jitsi-meet/libs/external_api.min.js;
---
>     root /usr/share/jitsi-meet/libs;
65c65
<     alias /usr/share/jitsi-meet/$1/$2;
---
>     root /usr/share/jitsi-meet;
104c104
<     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }}/http-bind?prefix=$prefix&$args;
---
>     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }};
118c118
<     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }}/xmpp-websocket?prefix=$prefix&$args;
---
>     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }};
157c157
<     rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
---
>     rewrite ^ / break;
181c181
<         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /http-bind;
---
>         rewrite ^ /http-bind?prefix=$prefix;
191c191
<         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /xmpp-websocket;
---
>         rewrite ^ /xmpp-websocket?prefix=$prefix;
201c201
<         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /_api/room-info;
---
>         rewrite ^ /_api/room-info;
208c208
<         rewrite ^/_load-test/(.*)$ /load-test/index.html break;
---
>         rewrite ^ /load-test/index.html break;
221c221
<         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /load-test/index.html break;
---
>         rewrite ^ /load-test/index.html break;

The critical changes are as follows:
104c104
<     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }}/http-bind?prefix=$prefix&$args;
---
>     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }};
118c118
<     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }}/xmpp-websocket?prefix=$prefix&$args;
---
>     proxy_pass {{ $XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE }};
181c181
<         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /http-bind;
---
>         rewrite ^ /http-bind?prefix=$prefix;
191c191
<         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /xmpp-websocket;
---
>         rewrite ^ /xmpp-websocket?prefix=$prefix;

All other changes are purely optimizations.
The final configuration I finished with is as follows:
docker-conpose.yml
services:

  project_one_jitsi_web:
    image: jitsi/web:stable
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"        # Change to an available port on the host
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
      - project_one_jitsi_jvb
    volumes:
      # Modified `base.html` file to be included via nginx SSI
      - ./base.html:/usr/share/jitsi-meet/base.html
      # Modified `meet.conf` nginx configuration template
      - ./meet.conf:/defaults/meet.conf

  project_one_jitsi_prosody:
    image: jitsi/prosody:stable
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network

  project_one_jitsi_jicofo:
    image: jitsi/jicofo:stable
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
      - project_one_jitsi_prosody

  project_one_jitsi_jvb:
    image: jitsi/jvb:stable
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "10000:10000/udp"
    env_file:
      - .jitsi_env_demo
    networks:
      - backend_network
    depends_on:
      - project_one_jitsi_prosody

networks:
  backend_network:

.jitsu_env_demo
# Don't have this file
#CONFIG=~/.jitsi-meet-cfg
# HTTP port will be changed via docker-compose mapping
#HTTP_PORT=8000
TZ=UTC
XMPP_DOMAIN=backend_network
XMPP_SERVER=project_one_jitsi_prosody
XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE=http://project_one_jitsi_prosody:5280
# Replace this with your actial domain name
PUBLIC_URL=https://project-one.org

ENABLE_IPV6=0
# All the HTTPS terminating will be done via the top level nginx reverse proxy
DISABLE_HTTPS=1
ENABLE_HTTP_REDIRECT=0
ENABLE_LETS_ENCRYPT=0

JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIGASI_XMPP_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIGASI_TRANSCRIBER_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIBRI_RECORDER_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously
JIBRI_XMPP_PASSWORD=fake_password_obviously

RESTART_POLICY=unless-stopped
JITSI_IMAGE_VERSION=stable

Main nginx.conf location for the Jitsi Meet service:
location /v_call_ser/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    # WebSocket protocol endpoint proxying
    location /v_call_ser/xmpp-websocket {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}

It turns out that the WebSocket connection is always requested using the HTTPS protocol, making it mandatory to listen on TCP port 443 in the main nginx configuration.
The solution seems to work at first glance, though I haven't conducted thorough testing.
